# Building PostgreSQL from source on Windows

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm trying to build `PosgreSQL` in Eclipse CDT Mars on Windows using the MinGW-64 gcc 5.3.0

I installed `MSYS2` and used `pacman` to update all the software that came with it and install gcc etc.

I downloaded the PostgreSQL source code and tried to follow the [docs](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse#Configure_source_code) **but can't figure out where to download the dependencies?** 1. `libreadline5-dev`, 2. `zlib1g-dev`, 3. `bison (YACC)`, 4. `flex` and where to save them to on disk?

I ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME/project --enable-depend --enable-cassert --enable-debug` and it seems to have completed with no errors, **but I do not see anything at `$HOME/project`?**

I installed Eclipse CDT and added the include paths to the Environment: 
[image: Screenshot of Eclipse Environment]

I imported the project as Existing Code as Makefile Project.

When I try to `build` the project Eclipse says `Info: Nothing to build for postgres`

When I try to run it a dialog box says `Unable to Launch.  The selection can not be launched and there are no recent launches`

How can I run/debug PostgreSQL in Eclipse on Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build PostgreSQL with MSYS2 and MinGW-w64, and I documented it in a video tutorial: [How to build PostgreSQL from source on Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BJmuZT5IPE)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend just using the prebuilt postgresql package provided by MSYS2.  To install the 64-bit version, run:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql
```

You can see the scripts that were used to build it here:

https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-postgresql

Comment: I don't want to use a prebuilt package, I want to build it from source.  I will check out the scripts you cited.  Upvoting your answer for now.  Thanks!